# Calculated Column Based Off Current Row and N-Rows After

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am working through 1000+ rows of stock data and I am currently loading it in a dataframe (I am also new to using pandas but currently it's amazing and I am still learning):

```
          open      high       low     close    volume        date
0     339.0500  339.6100  336.6200  337.2300  68054244  2020-08-19
1     338.3400  339.1000  336.6100  338.6400  38733908  2020-08-18
2     337.9400  338.3400  336.8517  337.9100  34496002  2020-08-17
3     336.4100  337.4200  335.6200  336.8400  47260390  2020-08-14
4     336.6100  338.2514  335.8300  336.8300  41816146  2020-08-13
...        ...       ...       ...       ...       ...         ...
5229  138.6250  139.1093  136.7812  137.8750   7431500  1999-11-05
5230  136.7500  137.3593  135.7656  136.5312   7907500  1999-11-04
5231  136.0000  136.3750  135.1250  135.5000   7222300  1999-11-03
5232  135.9687  137.2500  134.5937  134.5937   6516900  1999-11-02
5233  136.5000  137.0000  135.5625  135.5625   4006500  1999-11-01
```

I have a dynamic array of averages for simple moving averages and I want to perform that calculation for every row based off a dynamic selection of column, e.g., I've chose a 5-day simple moving average based off the `open` column:

```
          open      high       low     close    volume        date       5-day avg
0      |339.0500|  339.6100  336.6200  337.2300  68054244  2020-08-19      |337.67|
1     >|338.3400|  339.1000  336.6100  338.6400  38733908  2020-08-18     >297.585
2     >|337.9400|  338.3400  336.8517  337.9100  34496002  2020-08-17       ...
3     >|336.4100|  337.4200  335.6200  336.8400  47260390  2020-08-14       ...
4     >|336.6100|  338.2514  335.8300  336.8300  41816146  2020-08-13       ...
5229  >138.6250  139.1093  136.7812  137.8750   7431500  1999-11-05         ...
5230   136.7500  137.3593  135.7656  136.5312   7907500  1999-11-04
5231   136.0000  136.3750  135.1250  135.5000   7222300  1999-11-03
5232   135.9687  137.2500  134.5937  134.5937   6516900  1999-11-02
5233   136.5000  137.0000  135.5625  135.5625   4006500  1999-11-01
```

The closest I've got to is:

```
for avg in avgs:
            overview[avg] = {}
            for i in range(avg):
                overview[avg][i] = {}
                overview[avg][i] = df.loc[df['date'] <= str((date - td(days=(avg - i)))), ['close']].head(avg).sum(numeric_only=True).div(avg).to_json()
```

But I feel it is a bit clunky and not a very efficient method. I've looked at doing:

```
df['5-Day Avg'] = df['open'].head(5).sum().div(5) ....
```

But does not do what I'd like it to do as I am constantly grabbing from the top and not from the current index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort values and use `df.rolling(5)['open'].mean()`

```
df = df.sort_values('date')
df['5-day avg'] = df.rolling(5)['open'].mean()
df = df.sort_values('date', ascending=False)
df
Out[184]: 
          open      high       low     close    volume        date  5-day avg
0     339.0500  339.6100  336.6200  337.2300  68054244  2020-08-19  337.67000
1     338.3400  339.1000  336.6100  338.6400  38733908  2020-08-18  297.58500
2     337.9400  338.3400  336.8517  337.9100  34496002  2020-08-17  257.26700
3     336.4100  337.4200  335.6200  336.8400  47260390  2020-08-14  216.87900
4     336.6100  338.2514  335.8300  336.8300  41816146  2020-08-13  176.79074
5229  138.6250  139.1093  136.7812  137.8750   7431500  1999-11-05  136.76874
5230  136.7500  137.3593  135.7656  136.5312   7907500  1999-11-04        NaN
5231  136.0000  136.3750  135.1250  135.5000   7222300  1999-11-03        NaN
5232  135.9687  137.2500  134.5937  134.5937   6516900  1999-11-02        NaN
5233  136.5000  137.0000  135.5625  135.5625   4006500  1999-11-01        NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) method in pandas with window size to calculate the rolling mean  and [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) the result.

```
df['5-Day Avg'] = df['open'].rolling(5).mean().shift(periods=-4)
```